# Ionic Google Maps Markers from JSON

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic App using google maps. I am trying to populate the map with pin markers from a json file, however it is not working properly. Also the next exercise I would like to get the pin map markers from an api file with the structure `"data" : [{ "json":json, ... }]` Your help would be much appreciated.

Locations.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

declare var google;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-locations',
  templateUrl: 'locations.html'
})
export class LocationsPage {

@ViewChild('mapContainer') mapContainer: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public geolocation: Geolocation, private http: Http) {

}
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.displayGoogleMap();
  this.getMarkers();
}
displayGoogleMap() {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);

  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
getMarkers() {
  this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json')
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('my data: ', data);
    this.addMarkersToMap(data);
  });
}
addMarkersToMap(markers) {
  for(let marker of markers) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
    var locations = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: marker.title});
    locations.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
}
```

markers.json

```
[
{
  "latitude": 57.77504388,
  "longitude": 14.18557048,
  "name": "Kålgårdens rastgård"
},
{
  "latitude": 57.77474066,
  "longitude": 14.25457835,
  "name": "Öxnegården"
},
{
  "latitude": 57.7630705,
  "longitude": 14.0808624,
  "name": "Västersjön"
}
]
```

locations.html

```
<ion-content>
    <div #mapContainer id="mapContainer"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: So are you getting errors or what happens?

Comment: Google map appears and no errors. My console is spitting out the data `my data:  Array(3)
0
:
{latitude: 57.77504388, longitude: 14.18557048, name: "Kålgårdens rastgård"}
1
:
{latitude: 57.77474066, longitude: 14.25457835, name: "Öxnegården"}
2
:
{latitude: 57.7630705, longitude: 14.0808624, name: "Västersjön"}
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: Ok can you console log “this” inside addMarkersToMap method?

Comment: It is giving me the class name of the LocationsPage and a whole bunch of data regarding it, something we are looking for exactly in there?

Comment: I seemed to have figured it out, I put this.getMarkers(); inside of displayGoogleMap() { function as it was firing off in the load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have figured it out, I put this.getMarkers(); inside of displayGoogleMap() { function as it was firing off in the load