# Ionic Google Maps Markers JSON Not Displaying

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

Related to this question [Ionic Google Maps Markers from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814808/ionic-google-map-markers-from-json)

I have a Ionic App using google maps. I am trying to populate the map with pin markers from json API point, the map is displaying correctly but not the pins.

I believe I am not accessing the data properly through these functions - `getMarkers()` & `addMarkersToMap()`. I can see the data in the console no problem `console.log('my data: ', data);`

Your help would be much appreciated.

Locations.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

declare var google;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-locations',
  templateUrl: 'locations.html'
})
export class LocationsPage {

@ViewChild('mapContainer') mapContainer: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public geolocation: Geolocation, private http: Http) {

}
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.displayGoogleMap();

}
displayGoogleMap() {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
 this.getMarkers();
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
getMarkers() {
  this.http.get('json file')
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('my data: ', data);
    this.addMarkersToMap(data);
  });
}
addMarkersToMap(markers) {
for(let marker of markers) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
    var locations = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, name: marker.title});
    locations.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
}
```

json dummy data structure

```
{
  "message": "Successfully retrieved locator list.",
  "data": [
   {
      "Id": 160,
      "Name": "Bob Bob",  
      "Latitude": -36.299927, 
      "Longitude": 144.517076
   }
  ]
}
```

locations.html

```
<ion-content>
    <div #mapContainer id="mapContainer"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with this `.map(res => res.json().data)` adding `.data` to get this property in my json which i believe is an observable? Got the answer from here - https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-manipulate-data-in-ionic-2-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

hmm, where is a `marker.title` in the json?

I think you can debug like this,

```
addMarkersToMap(markers) {
for(let marker of markers) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
    var locations = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: marker.title});
    console.log(marker);
    console.log(marker.title);
    console.log(position);
    console.log(locations);
    locations.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

and you may need to fix lat, lng marker's center for debugging,

```
displayGoogleMap() {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.299927, 144.517076); # fix current lat, lng for debug
  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
 this.getMarkers();
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

---

the reason why get no console messages is the json structure is something wrong. maybe you need use "res.json().data". like this,

```
getMarkers() {
  this.http.get('json file')
  .map((res) => res.json().data)
                        // ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. I get no console messages in the functions addMarkersToMap() function it is not even getting to the for loop i think. However with this json structure it all works perfectly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814808/ionic-google-maps-markers-from-json - it must be to do with nested json format getting passed

Comment: Ah yes sorry title should be Name

Comment: the reason why get no console messages is the json structure is something wrong. maybe you need use "res.json().data".